# How do I make variables in PHP and pass them to Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby

I have a script running in Ruby, and another in PHP, and, for my needs it's not possible to make it all run in the same scripting language.

I want to use PHP to create a variable in Ruby. Currently, I have this code:

PHP:

```
$config = fopen("config.txt","w+");
fwrite($config,$sArguments);
fclose($config);
```

Ruby:

```
while true do
file = File.new("config.txt", "r")
config = file.gets
file.close
end
```

The PHP will write the next configuration in a file and Ruby will read it and turn it into a variable. It works, but Ruby has to work on reading and reading the file, and it sometimes fail to read it correct, so this code is very badly optimized.

Is there a faster way to pass information from a PHP script to a Ruby script?

Comment: Make an API for the two to use to "talk"

Comment: FYI, `while true do ... end` can be replaced with simply `loop do ... end`. And your file IO with just `config = File.read('config.txt')`.

Comment: are you worried about conflicts

Comment: why not write the values to a database like sqlite and read them from ruby? or store the values as json?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say what the problem is exactly from the information given, but when you say Ruby sometimes fails to read I'm guessing it's your Ruby script reading the file when PHP is half-way through writing it.

An easy fix would be for PHP to write it to a temporary file and then move or rename the temporary file so it can be picked up by the Ruby script. Move/rename is atomic so there is no chance of a half written file being read.

A couple of improvements you could also make:

- Use something like the [listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) gem to only read the file on an update.
- I'm not sure what data you're passing, but you could use something like YAML as an interchange format. Catch any parsing exceptions and log the received data to aid debugging.

Taking a step back, if you're on a "real O/S", a simpler option would be to use message-based IPC via Unix sockets, assuming persistence is not a concern. Have a look at this page on "[Introduction to IPC in Ruby](http://www.jstorimer.com/2012/04/19/intro-to-ruby-ipc.html)" for a good intro with examples on passing messages between processes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in PHP but I think "[How to run Ruby code from Python (Python-Ruby bridge)](http://www.decalage.info/python/ruby_bridge)" provides some ways of how to accomplish communication between the two languages. Although the page speaks of Ruby-Python communication, I'm pretty sure some of the suggestions can be implemented for Ruby and PHP.

One solution is to use XML-RPC to transfer simple data types from PHP to Ruby. Ruby has native support for XML-RPC and I think there are libraries for PHP to enable support for XML-RPC.

You can also use pipes. That is, you call your PHP script via Ruby's `IO.popen`. I've done something similar for Ruby-Python in "[Feasibility of using pipe for ruby-python communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765120/feasibility-of-using-pipe-for-ruby-python-communication)" but I have not really evaluated the performance.